# Como eliminar registros agregados en mi tabla javascript

Tags: javascript, html

espero se encuentren muy bien.

Tengo el siguiente código:

este script me trae en una tabla el personal que seleccione.

```
<script>
    function guardartwo(){

        var _personas= document.getElementById("personas").value;

        var fila="<tr><td>Persona:</td><td>"+
            "<input type='text' name='personal_asignado[]' value='"+_personas+"' readonly>"+
            "</td>";

        var btn = document.createElement("TR");
        btn.innerHTML=fila;
        document.getElementById("pasignado").appendChild(btn);
    }

</script>
```

Y aquí esta la tabla:
Como funciona esto de la siguiente manera: yo selecciono una persona por medio del select, luego presiono el boton que dice + y el script me trae la persona seleccionada para luego guardarlo en la base de datos
hasta allí todo funciona perfecto.

```
<h2 class="tm-block-title">Personal asignado</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td><font color="#ffffff">Persona:</font></td>  
    <td><select name="personal_asignado[]" id="tecnico_asignado" class="camp" style="width:200px;" >
    <option></option>           
    <option value="Persona 1">Persona 1</option>
    <option value="Persona 2">Persona 2</option>
    <option value="Persona 3">Persona 3</option>
    <option value="Persona 4">Persona 4</option>
    <option value="Persona 5">Persona 5</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>

<table>
<tbody id="pasignado">

</tbody>
</table>
<br>

<button onclick="guardartwo()">+</button>
```

La idea de esto es poder guardar las personas que necesite, ejemplo si solo necesito una pues solo sera una persona, pero si necesito mas de una que de igual forma lo permite hacer, el problema es que tengo el boton de + pero no tengo un boton de - osea que me permita quitar una persona agregada erroneamente.

De que manera podria agregar otro boton de menos (-) que al presinar me quite una persona.

Quedo atento a cualquier ayuda, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
/******************************************/

// nuevo método para eliminar la fila, recibe como parámetro el botón presionado 
// y navega hasta el nodo de la fila para eliminarla

 function eliminarFila(boton){
 // navegar hasta el nodo fila
 fila = boton.parentNode.parentNode;
 // navegar al nodo superior de la fila y borrar la fila
 fila.parentNode.removeChild(fila);
 
 
}

/******************************************/

function guardartwo(){

var _personas= document.getElementById("tecnico_asignado").value;
  
var fila="<tr><td>Persona:</td><td>"+
            "<input type='text' name='personal_asignado[]' value='"+_personas+"' readonly>"+
            "</td>" + 
            
 // botón que llama al método eliminar fila y pasa como parámetro
 // el botón
"<td><button onclick='eliminarFila(this)'>eliminar</button></td>" ;

var btn = document.createElement("TR");
btn.innerHTML=fila;
document.getElementById("pasignado").appendChild(btn);
    }
```

```html
<h2 class="tm-block-title">Personal asignado</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td><font color="#ffffff">Persona:</font></td> 
 <td><select name="personal_asignado[]" id="tecnico_asignado" class="camp" style="width:200px;" >
    <option></option>           
    <option value="Persona 1">Persona 1</option>
 <option value="Persona 2">Persona 2</option>
 <option value="Persona 3">Persona 3</option>
 <option value="Persona 4">Persona 4</option>
 <option value="Persona 5">Persona 5</option>
 </select></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>

<table>
<tbody id="pasignado">

</tbody>
</table>
<br>

<button onclick="guardartwo()">+</button>
```

Comment: perfecto muchisimas gracias, me sirvió completamente.